# Google SpreadSheet Custom Date Format

Tags: csv, google-sheets, date-format

I'm looking for a easy formula to generate this type of Date Format:

10:35 PM August 12th 2013

hh:mm AM/PM Month dd yyyy

It's for the MarketMeSuite CSV scheduling utility that only excepts that format when uploading scheduled tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this format is possible using the `Utilities.formatDate()` utility. Please see [Oracles Class SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for java as this uses the same formats. You should be able to get your desired format using the below formatting.

`h:mm a MMMMM d yyyy`

The only issues would be with the `th` or `nd` or `rd` or `st` after the date. But you could use some if statements to format that depending on the number, I'll let you work on that :)

The final string of the above would be -

`9:16 PM April 15 2013`

So the final date object creation would be.

`Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "h:mm a MMMMM d yyyy")`

**EDIT**

I've just realised you might not be talking about getting this format in a script but actually just calling it in a cell. If so you still need to create a custom function, so add the below code to a new script.

```
function getDate() {
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "h:mm a MMMMM d yyyy")
   return date;
}
```

Then you can call it back in a cell with `=getDate()`